# Count of number of cases within a range in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, counting, countif

I am trying to count the number of employee work days within the following ranges:

`< 30

> = 30 and < 90
> = 90 and <180`.

For the number of employees that worked for more than 30 days and less than 90 days, I tried the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS(P10:P21,">=90" AND P10:P21,">=180")`

Should I use an IF AND formula instead?

All help is welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try just:

```
=COUNTIFS(P10:P21,">=90", P10:P21, "<=180")
```